# WinJS ListView - Control scrolling from javascript/button

Tags: javascript, winjs

Is there a way to control the scrolling of a WinJs ListView from Javascript? I'm trying to create custom scroll arrows...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer .scrollPosition!

```
 this._scrollContainer.winControl.scrollPosition = newPos
```